# Phonegap: file transfer fail on Android

Tags: android, cordova, upload

I try to upload a file from my android phone to 000webhost by using Filetransfer.upload. It returns the error code 1. What does the error code 1 mean? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {

            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="file";
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";



            var params = new Object();
            params.value1 = "test";
            params.value2 = "param";

            options.params = params;
            options.chunkedMode = false;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, "http://tom.host88.com/upload1.php", win, fail, options,true);

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll find the FileTransferError object and error codes in phonegap-x-x-x.js. Error code 1 is a FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR.

Comment: When I try to upload an available image from my android phone, it returns FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR. My path is "file:///sdcard/image.jpg". Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the path?

Comment: You call to upload has too many arguments http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_upload. try: ft.upload(imageURI, "http://tom.host88.com/upload1.php", win, fail, options)

Comment: I have tried ft.upload(imageURI, "tom.host88.com/upload1.php", win, fail, options) but it still display FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR :(. When I try to capture an image and send it directly to the server, it works. Why is that? What happens to my file path?

Comment: Hi, I try the adb logcat and I found it: FileUploader: Java.io.FileNotFoundException /file/sdcard/image.jpg please help........

Comment: Basically the file /sdcard/image.jpg does not exist. Run "adb shell" and look at your sd card to see what's going on.

Comment: How?  I've got the same issue going on?

Comment: i'm having a similar problem. can you share some light on how you got it working?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, or rather error, when uploading file to an asmx service. Cordova told me that i had an Http 500 error code:1 (and a confusing FileNotFoundException from java). I found that my asmx service had not enabled POST properly, which caused the error. Try this config in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

After puzlzing a bit (I see some lacks on the phonegap documentation) i got it working, see my complete code:

[android phonegap camera and image uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447336/android-phonegap-camera-and-image-uploading)